# How do I Upload an Image with a URL to a Canvas in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a website where you can edit photos. I have implemented a button that lets the user upload an image from their computer. However, I want the user to be able to load an image-URL as well. I have looked everywhere to find how I can implement this feature, but every post just says how to upload from the computer.

What I want is a input where the user can paste a URL, and a button you click to load the URL onto the canvas.

Here are the neccasary parts of my HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" class="urlLoader" id="urlLoader" placeholder="https://example.com/this-image.jpg">
<button type="button" name="button" class="loadURL">Load URL</button>

<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an URL you can do something like this:

```
const url = document.querySelector('#url');
const loadURL = document.querySelector('.loadURL');
const canvas = document.querySelector('#viewport');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const getImage = () => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = url.value;
  image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
};
loadURL.addEventListener('click', getImage);
```

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>
  <input
    type="url"
    name="url"
    id="url"
    placeholder="https://example.com"
    pattern="https://.*"
    size="30"
    required
    />
<button type="button" name="button" class="loadURL">Load URL</button>

<canvas id="viewport" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```